# SPA server side framework

Tags: php, asp.net

I am developing a new page and can not decide witch server technology I should use. I will try to describe as best I can, what I am making and hoping someone will have some advice for me.

The choice I have to made is PHP vs ASP.NET and in case of ASP.NET MsSQL vs PostgreSQL.
I must say I already spend a few months comparing and experimenting with this 2 products (and know both for many years, but for small projects).

So if I get to the point:
My web page will definitely be SPA. I don't intend to change some div content to achieve that, but open different content in [dialogs](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/) or if you know KendoUI [windows](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/window/ajax).
Everything else could be adapted to the selected framework. I don't plan to have many different views, but those few will heavily depend on data from database. The core of my page will be one view bind to a table with few 10/100 thousand records.

I am using jQuery to get data from server. I started with PHP, but it soon became very large project, tons of files for handling users, roles, access to file system, managing database, quering database, editing database, handling different language support... I use try version of zend studio which is great framework (you get debugger which is a little bugging from time to time) but can not compete with visual studio.

I also read on internet that all big sites (except SO) use PHP because they started small and when they became big there is no way to migrate to different server technology.

I get problems with requires files (there are to many) if I include from index.php there is different path that from AjaxCall/ProcessLogin.php. I always forgot to include some file and get unexpected result in client. ASP.NET would solve this problem. I huge disadvantage is also unknown types in PHP. I call function which return array of objects populate from database and I don't know nothing about object structure, but when using LINQ to SQL I know everything. It bothers me also that can not have 2 functions with same name and different parameters. LINQ to SQL is also amazing. And so on. Those who use both of them, you can say what advantages has developing in Visual studio c# over Zend studio in PHP.

I know (from what I read in past months) that PHP will get me better performance, that sometimes could be slower because of the interpreter. Again, I just use functions to get some data and on client side use telerik KendoUI for rendering contents.

My questions that I can not answer myself is is ASP.NET the right choise if I don't plan to use any other feature then [WebMethod] (any server side events, ASP.NET controls...)? Probably I should go with ASP.NET Web API or ASP.NET single page application? I read [tutorial](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) how can I call method with jQuery. I also found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21913701/are-server-side-mvc-frameworks-still-relevant-in-single-page-applications) thread. But I need to decide if I stick with PHP and do some hard work for stuff that I mention up, or I should use ASP.NET, get some really nice stuff on account of performance.

I must say that cost are not the problem. Hosting windows server, Visual studio ...

Answer (score 2):

tldr; use PHP's [Laravel](http://laravel.com) Framework, it's a very good framework to start and it grows with you. Also it's heavily influenced by ASP.NET and Rails, just for the PHP world. Build your REST API with laravel and use jQuery for the AJAX stuff. Querying the database (e.g. postgres) with Laravel is amazing, just write something like `User::where('age', 21)->get();`.

Answer (score -1):

Check spa-cart.com

Already much features with PHP SPA CMS